# how to load double quotes data of fields in hive table without excluding double quotes?

Tags: hive, bigdata, hive-table

Can I know the working table property for splitting the records as shown below.

Input field - 123,"456","INDIA","INDIA",789,"DELHI INDIA, PIN. North INDIA","101","NEW Delhi ","LOCATION"

Expected hive output("|" indicates split) - 123 |  "456" |  "INDIA" |  "INDIA" |  789 |  "DELHI INDIA, PIN. North INDIA" |  "101" |  "NEW Delhi " |  "LOCATION"

I tried ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde', the splitting is as expected but double quotes are not included.